# Solve initial value problem $y'=t-y+1, y(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve initial value problem $y'=t-y+1, y(0)=1$

The problem says to use technology. But I am wondering if I can do this by integrating factor.

$y'+y=t+1$

$e^t*(y'+y)=e^t*(t+1)$

$\int (e^t*y)'$=$\int (e^t*t+e^t)$
I am stuck on this step, I don't think integration by parts works for the right side. Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that if you substitute $y=z+t$, then the $t$'s cancel on the right. And at the same time, $y'=z'+1$, and the $1$s cancel. So $z'=-z$.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I still don't quite see in the equation.

Comment: $\int e^t=e^t$ and $I=\int te^t=te^t-\int e^t=te^t-e^t$

Comment: I'm suggesting that if you introduce a new function $z$ that is related to $y$ via $y=z+t$ then it simplifies your differential equation. You end up with a very easy differential equation to solve for $z$. And then you can remember that $y=z+t$ to get the solution for $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear ODE is:
$$y'+y=t+1, y(0)=1$$
Its integrating factor is
$$I=\exp \int 1 dt= e^{t}$$
Then
$$y=e^{-t} \int e^{t} (t+1) dt+C e^{-t} \implies y= t+C e^{t}, \implies C=1.$$
So finally the solution os:
$$y=t+e^t$$

The general linear ODE is written as
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x) y= Q(x) \implies \frac{d}{dx}[y e^{\int P dx}]=Q(x)$$
Let us call the integrating factor $e^{\int P dx}$ as $I$
, then $$\implies y=I^{-1} \int I Q dx+ C I^{-1}$$

Comment: Can you tell me how you get $e^{-t} \int e^t*(t+1)dt$ to t?

Comment: You may see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

For your question:

$\int e^t=e^t$ and $I=\int te^t=te^t-\int e^t=te^t-e^t$

---

Another approach:
$$y′=t−y+1,$$
Rewrite it simply as:
$$y′-1=t−y$$
$$(y-t)'=-(y-t)$$
$$\frac {(y-t)'}{(y-t)}=-1$$
$$(\ln (y-t))'=-1$$
Integrate
$$\ln (y-t)=-t+c$$
$$ \implies y(t)=t+ce^{-t}$$